# seeking a simple description of what SSH secured VNC does with these arguments

Tags: ssh, vnc

[At this link is information on securing VNC over SSH](http://blog.cheapvps.co.uk/index.php/2011/03/29/how-to-setup-vnc-over-ssh-on-ubuntu-server/).  Apparently, the server invocation of VNC is unchanged. And the difference between unsecured and secured is due to invoking SSH with these arguments, shown, and then invoking the viewer with arguments that are different from what would be done in the unsecured scenario.

```
ssh user@server -L 5901/127.0.0.1/5901
vncviewer 127.0.0.1:5901
```

Reading the SSH man page's description of the `-L` option is clear as mud.  Of course 127.0.0.1 is a local address but other than that, please explain what each argument instructs the corresponding program to do and why 5901 is used when 5900 is known to be the VNC port.  Is the author (carelessly?) presuming that I use the :1 argument on the server side? Why do we loopback to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Reading the SSH man page's description of the -L option is clear as mud. Of course 127.0.0.1 is a local address but other than that, please explain what each argument instructs the corresponding program to do

The option `-L 5901/127.0.0.1/5901` (more commonly written as `5901:127.0.0.1:5901`) instructs the SSH client to set up a TCP "tunnel", listening on port `5901` on the client machine, and forward all connections to `127.0.0.1:5901` of the *server* machine. Afterwards, `vncviewer 127.0.0.1:5901` is used to connect to the client side of the tunnel. *ssh* accepts the connections, and instructs the SSH server (`sshd`) to open an identical connection server-side.

- On client: *vncviewer* ⇆ 127.0.0.1:5901 (*ssh*)
- On server: *sshd* ⇆ 127.0.0.1:5901 (*vncserver*)

As you can see, loopback is used because *vncviewer* only connects to *ssh*, which is running on the same computer. Similarly, both *sshd* and *vncserver* run on the same server.

---

Tunnelling to a third host might make a clearer example:

- ```
  ssh gatewayhost -L 1357:securehost:5901
  vncviewer 127.0.0.1:1357
  ```
- On client: *vncviewer* ⇆ 127.0.0.1:1357 (*ssh*)
- On server: *sshd* ⇆ securehost:5901 (*vncserver*)

---

> and why 5901 is used when 5900 is known to be the VNC port. Is the author (carelessly?) presuming that I use the :1 argument on the server side?

Yes, by providing `-L <any>/127.0.0.1/5901` the author assumes that the VNC server is listening on port 5901 (VNC display `:1`).